# JQuery Form Validation To Check 2 Fields

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I have a contact form which is validated using JQuery so that certain fields have to contain a value before sending.  I have 2 fields (Telephone & E-Mail) that either one or both must be filled in so I'm using this code to validate:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var nameok = 0;
        var telephoneok = 0;
        var emailok = 0;
        var messageok = 0;
        var validok = 1;
        var contactok = 1;
        // Name Validation
        $('#name').blur(function() {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            if (name.length < 1) {
                nameok = 0;
            } else {
                nameok = 1;
            }
        });
        // Telephone Validation
        $('#telephone').blur(function() {
            var telephone = $("#telephone").val();
            if (telephone.length < 1) {
                telephoneok = 0;
            } else {
                telephoneok = 1;
            }
        });
        // E-Mail Validation
        $('#email').blur(function() {
            var email = $("#email").val();
            if (email.length < 1) {
                emailok = 0;
            } else {
                emailok = 1;
            }
        });
        // Message Validation
        $('#message').blur(function() {
            var message = $("#message").val();
            if (message.length < 1) {
                messageok = 0;
            } else {
                messageok = 1;
            }
        });
        // Valid Validation
        $('#valid').blur(function() {
            var valid = $("#valid").val();
            if (valid.length > 0) {
                validok = 0;
            } else {
                validok = 1;
            }
        });
        // Contact Validation
        if (telephoneok == 0 && emailok == 0) {
            contactok = 0;
        } else {
            contactok = 1;
        }
        // Submit button action
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            if (nameok == 1 && messageok == 1 && validok == 1 && contactok = 1) {
                $('#submit').hide();
                $('#form').submit();
            } else {
                $('#submit').show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        //End
    });
</script>
```

However it's still sending the form if neither of the Telephone or Email fields are comeplete.  I'm pretty sure that the error lies in the `Contact Validation` section but what am I missing?

Comment: try if (telephoneok == 0 && emailok == 0) { contactok = 0;} else { contactok = 1;} and you also need to add a check for contactok in your submit. you're not checking for contactok and hence it is passing through even if its empty.

Comment: Thanks @Sushil but now the form isn't being submitted at all

Comment: can you put an alert on all the 4 values that you get in the click event? probably one of the values is not true

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this sort of coding, how do I alert?

Comment: try putting alert(nameok); or console.log(nameok); do this for all the 4 values. use either alert or console.log. if you're using console.log you can check the values in the developer console that you get when u click on F12 in your browser.

Comment: It's alerting me that contactok = 0 - But I still can't see where the error is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80095/discussion-between-sushil-and-foot-promoter).